# Help with branches

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees, branching

I'm trying to do something like this, but I doon't know how to creat [+silábico] or organize "NUC" in an equal high. Thanks!!

Here is what I used:
(I've tried "[{[-silábico]},before drawing Vocálico={y=-1.0cm,x=0.8cm},anchor= south west]", but it didn't work :/).

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper, doubleside]{article}%showtrims
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left,modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{multicol,textcomp,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{textcase,graphicx,lastpage,covington}
\usepackage[makeindex,split]{splitidx}
\usepackage[tone,extra]{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
                                    [Nuc
                                    [x
                                    [Raiz 
                                    [Vocálico
                                    [Altura
                                    [\textsc{[+{alto}]}
                                %   [{[+recuado]}
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ] 
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                \end{forest} \hspace{0.4cm}

                                 \begin{forest} 
                                        [\textsc{[+{ac}]}
                                        [Nuc
                                        [x
                                        [Raiz
                                        ]
                                        ]
                                        ] 
                                        ]
                                    \end{forest} \hspace{0.2cm} $\rightarrow$ \hspace{0.2cm}
                                    \begin{forest} 
                                            [Nuc
                                            [x
                                            [Raiz
                                            ]
                                            ]
                                            ] 
                                        \end{forest} \hspace{0.4cm}

                                            \begin{forest} 
                                                [\textsc{[+{ac}]}
                                                [Nuc
                                                [x
                                                [Raiz
                                                ]
                                                ]
                                                ] 
                                                ]
                                            \end{forest} 


                        \end{document}
```

**Expected output**

[image: expected putput]

Comment: Are you fully convinced that you want to use forest for that? Why not just a `tikz` chain or matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I really love forest and continue to be stunned by what it can do, in this case I'd like to argue that it is easier to employ other tools. An arguably rather simple way is to use `tikz-cd` for that.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper, doubleside]{article}%showtrims
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1mm,
 /tikz/column 4/.append style={column sep=0.7cm}]
 & & {[+\text{ac}]}\arrow[d,dash] & & & & {[+\text{ac}]}\arrow[d,dash] &\\
 \text{x}\arrow[d,dash] & & \text{x}\arrow[d,dash] & & 
 \text{x}\arrow[d,dash,"="below=-2pt] & & \text{x}\arrow[d,dash] & \\
 \text{Nuc}\arrow[d,dash] & & \text{Nuc}\arrow[d,dash] & & 
 \text{Nuc}\arrow[d,dash] & & \text{Nuc}\arrow[d,dash] & \\
 \text{Raiz}\arrow[r,dash]\arrow[d,dash] & {[+\text{recuado}]} &
 \text{Raiz}\arrow[r,dash] & {[+\text{recuado}]} \arrow[r,Rightarrow]&
 \text{Raiz}\arrow[r,dash] & {[+\text{recuado}]} &
 \text{Raiz}\arrow[r,dash] & {[+\text{recuado}]}\\
 \text{Voc\'alico}\arrow[d,dash] & & & & & & & \\
 \text{Altura}\arrow[d,dash] & & & & & & & \\
 {[+\text{alto}]} & & & & & & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! tikz-cd  is a good idea! I didn't even know this package. Just one more thing: how can I draw the (=) between Nuc and x  above the third "Raiz"? Thanks @marmot!

Comment: @Amanda I added it, as  well as the missing line of `x`s. Note that your diagram is a bit wide for the page geometry. One possible way to slightly decrease the width of the diagram and make the horizontal lines longer is to replace `column sep=1mm` by `column sep=1.5mm,font=\small,`.

Comment: @ marmot thank you as always! My phd thesis will be much more clear thanks to your help. Thanks!